# How can I override mod_python's default 500 error when "wonky" Django config problems strike?

Tags: django, apache, mod-python

When Django is up, it handles 500 errors. When Django is screwed,
mod_python will throw a bare bones "Internal Server Error." This is
described well in the docs at the following link:

http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/deployment/modpython/#error-handling

My question: Is there a way to override that "Internal Server Error"
page without overriding all Django 500 pages? The only way I can find
to override it is by screwing around with Apache's ErrorDocument
setting, which will then override all 500s, whether handled by Django
or Apache.

Is there a way to negotiate that so Django handles Django errors, but
still customize the default message? I would love to know.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

For that VirtualHost or that configuration, you can specify the Apache HTTP 500 Error.  Implementing custom error messages is easy

Just add the line to your apache configuration

```
ErrorDocument 500 http://www.example.com/error_500.html
```

For more information: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/custom-error.html

Comment: Andrew, thanks for the tip. I've done what you said, and it works. But the downside is that it seems to override *all* 500 errors, even those that Django usually serves that are unrelated to the config issue. I'm looking for a solution that will only fire in a "pre-Django" error, like the one described in the link above, and all Django handle more "typical" 500 errors.